# symfony4: how do I configure dataFixture to write in test db

Tags: unit-testing, doctrine, symfony4

I want to load the testdata for my unit tests into the test db via DataFixtures.
The documentation says, that if I set the environment variable the test db should be used:

```
$ php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --env=test
Careful, database will be purged. Do you want to continue y/N ?y
  > purging database
  > loading App\DataFixtures\PropertyFixtures
  > loading App\DataFixtures\UserFixtures
  > loading App\DataFixtures\UserPropertyFixtures
```

However if I check the data end up in my default database.

Where do I configure my test db with symfony 4?

And where do I configure it, so that DataFixtures knows where to write?

For my functional tests I configured the db setting in the phpunit.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we did to solve it was the following. I don't know if that is a good way, so alternative solutions are still appreciated.

in ../config/packages there is the file doctrine.yaml

I copied the file in the folder ./config/packages/test and edited it in the following way:

```
parameters:
    # Adds a fallback DATABASE_URL if the env var is not set.
    # This allows you to run cache:warmup even if your
    # environment variables are not available yet.
    # You should not need to change this value.
    env(DATABASE_URL): ''

doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8
            collate: utf8_unicode_ci

        url: mysql://%db_user_test%:%db_password_test%@%db_host_test%:%db_port_test%/%db_name_test%
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
```

So what I changed was the like with the url: mysql....

In my parameters I had added the parameters db_user_test etc and used them to connect to the test db.

It works, but still I am not sure if this is how it should be done.